# Cast to TObject

Tags: sql, delphi, object

I am struggling to get the ItemIndex of my a Item in my TComoBox...
Usually that doesn't seem to be a hard thing to do for me... but somehow when i try to cast my String(which I got from a SQL select) to a TObject. That doesn't seem to work. I tried to debug my code with writing the String manually into the Object like so:

```
TObject('U');
```

That somehow does work, i just cant explain that...

The way i fill the ComoBox:

```
for i := Low(_VerkaufTypenBez) to High(_VerkaufTypenBez) do
begin
    CBBelegart.AddItem(VerkaufTypenBez(i), Tobject(VerkaufTypenShort[i]));
end;
```

The way i tried to set the Index:

```
CB.ItemIndex := CB.Items.IndexOfObject(TObject(SetIndexWithSQL('select top 1 * from KOMSAconfig_Allgemein', 'Belegart'))); //index = -1
helper := 'U';
CB.ItemIndex := CB.Items.IndexOfObject(TObject(helper)); //index = -1
CB.ItemIndex := CB.Items.IndexOfObject(TObject('U')); //index = 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you even using (fake)objects here? A string is not a TObject.

Comment: I don't get your point sorry. I have to use the String of the function "SetIndexWithSQL" that returns a String, "IndexOfObject" requires a TObject as parameter

Comment: How about `IndexOf`?

Comment: Well that would help if i had the exact Name of the Item, i only have the value of the Object it was inserted with...

Comment: Do you dynamically add or remove items in your combobox or is this only done once in the loop you show here? I think it is an better idea to hold a separate look-up list and rely on that.

Comment: I just call the loop once at FormCreate

Comment: Then surely you can just use ItemIndex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens when you try to use a visual control as if it were a general purpose container. A visual control is used purely for display and user interaction. Don't try to bend it to do more than that.

In your scenario it is pointless to attempt to add a second string into the combo box. Stop doing that. Change your loop that populates to be like so:

```
for i := Low(_VerkaufTypenBez) to High(_VerkaufTypenBez) do
begin
  CBBelegart.Items.Add(VerkaufTypenBez(i));
end;
```

The other string is held in an array like structure and seemingly can be accessed like this: `VerkaufTypenShort[i]`. So, if you want to lookup the index of a particular value, that can be done like so:

```
function GetIndexFromShortString(const Value: string): Integer;
begin
  for Result := Low(_VerkaufTypenBez) to High(_VerkaufTypenBez) do
    if VerkaufTypenShort[Result]=Value then
      exit;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Notice that this function is completely independent of the visual control. You should strive to use visual controls for the bare minimum, and write your business logic without reference to any visual controls.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i'll take that

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here seems to be that you get two strings from your query, where one is used as display text and the other is needed for internal lookups (coming from a different query).

I see two ways to solve this:

- change your second query, so it returns the string, that is used in the combobox
- have a lookup in your form that connects both strings

For the second you could use a TDictionary. My approach here assumes that filling the combobox is done only in one loop and there aren't strings added or removed dynamically.

Add the Dictionary to your form:

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
...
private
  FLookUp: TDictionary<string, Integer>;
```

In the FormCreate and FormDestroy events create and destroy your Dictionary.

```
FLookUp := TDictionary<string, Integer>.Create;

FLookUp.Free;
```

In the loop you use to fill the Combobox, store the Indices and connect them to your lookup-strings (I just copied your loop, assuming that it works as is).

```
procedure TForm1.FillCombo;
var
  Index, I: Integer;
begin
  FLookUp.Clear;
  for i := Low(_VerkaufTypenBez) to High(_VerkaufTypenBez) do
  begin
    Index := CBBelegart.Items.Add(VerkaufTypenBez(i));
    FLookUp.Add(VerkaufTypenShort[i], Index);
  end;
end;
```

Now you can look for the correct Index using that Dictionary

```
function TForm1.GetIndexOfString(const Value: string): Integer;
begin
  if not FLookUp.TryGetValue(Value, Result) then
    Result := -1;
end;
```

Use it like

```
CB.ItemIndex := GetIndexOfString(SetIndexWithSQL(...));
```

Comment: No need to build a dictionary. The secondary strings appear to be held in a simple array.